# I can only run VS2013 in SafeMode

Tags: visual-studio, runtime-error, safe-mode

I am using windows 8.1 and visual studio 2013. I can only run VS2013 in safemode, otherwise it raises error at startup and close. It is same even I made a fresh install again. It is also same for the other versions as well (2012, 2010). How can I diagnoses the problem ,any idea?

Comment: Don't mention the error, it is not important.  Just say "it doesn't work".

Comment: Would the error it raises at startup be something you could share with us?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try:

1. Search for the service packs, I think for VS2013 there is the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.
2. Restart your pc after the installation.
3. Right clic, properties, Compatibility, Run as administrator or compatibility mode.

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921